# trim-directive-whitespaces remove undesired spaces

Tags: java, jsp, el, jsp-tags

I had activated **trim-directive-whitespaces** in my site recently, editing web.xml file on this way:

```
<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
  </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

This works fine but I found a weird behaivour in this type of situations:

```
${myMap['literal']} ${myMap['literal']}
Output:valuevalue
```

Notice that between 2 variables there are a whitespace, but this whitespace isn't printed since this web.xml change is enabled.

If y set some text between this variables the output is the desired:

```
${myMap['literal']}&#8203; ${myMap['literal']}
Output:value value
```

Note: this '`&#8203;`' is an empty char, but this works with any letter or other character

The way of get this myMap variables in my JSP is across a tag, using jspContetx from

```
getJspContext().setAttribute(key, map);//Map is an Map<String, Object>
```

I don't understand why this is removed from my JSP, when I used scriptlet or other vars this works fine. Any idea about this?